# Fortify: How to extract Build Label from FPR file using FPRUtility Tool

Tags: fortify

Does anyone know the command to extract the `Build Label` from FPR file using the FPRUtility tool?

I tried the below command but does not give the `Build Label`.

`sca18.20/bin/FPRUtility -information -search -project prevresults.fpr -query "[Build Label]" -f output.txt`

Attached snapshot from SSC which shows the field `[Build Label]` in which I am interested to extract using FPRUtility. This is required for one automation task.

[image]

Please note: I am using Fortify 18.20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot directly get the `Build Label` using `FPRUtility` from `.fpr` file.

To get the `Build Label` from `.fpr` file, we need to extract the `audit.fvdl` file from `.fpr` file and parse `audit.fvdl` to get the `Build Label`.

`.fpr` file is like a zip archive which can be extracted easily and `audit.fvdl` file is in `XML` format, hence parsing becomes easy. `Build Label` can be found with the tag `<Label>20.1.1.0.0_LINUX.X64_200427.0900</Label>`

Alternatively we can use `SSC API` to get the `Build Label` but we will need the `artifact ID` to get the info.

This was answered by a user in Fortify Community for my [question](https://community.microfocus.com/t5/Fortify-User-Discussions/How-to-extract-Build-Label-from-FPR-file-using-FPRUtility-Tool/td-p/2778598#M9018).